# MySQL empty rows show up only if table is empty

Tags: mysql

I have 2 MySQL tables, one is named `_campi` (Italian for `fields`) and one is `documenti` (Italian for `documents`).

I need to show all the rows from `_campi` and where there is a match in `documenti` this has to show in a field as result.

The weird behavior I cannot understand is that if `documenti`table is empty I get the expected result (10 rows with many null values, expected result), if documenti IS NOT empty I get only 2 rows as result.

This is the query:

```
SELECT *, campi_tipologie.valore_campo as tipo_doc FROM _campi as campi_tipologie
        LEFT JOIN documenti
        ON documenti.doc_type = campi_tipologie.id_campo
        WHERE campi_tipologie.categoria = "documenti-immobili"
        AND (campi_tipologie.codec = 2 OR campi_tipologie.codec = 0)
        AND (documenti.id_immobile IS NULL OR documenti.id_immobile = 422)
        ORDER BY id_campo
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you also post some sample data that would help us reproduce the issue and hence have a clearer look into your problem?

Comment: Move the 422 criterion to the ON clause and never use `SELECT *`

Comment: Oh, and one of the beautiful things about aliases is that they can be shorter than the word they alias.

Comment: @Strawberry hahahaha you are right, they shouldn't be longer.... hahaha Tks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT campi 
     , I
     , actually
     , want
     , c.valore_campo tipo_doc
  FROM _campi c
  LEFT 
  JOIN documenti d
    ON d.doc_type = c.id_campo
   AND d.id_immobile = 422
 WHERE c.categoria = "documenti-immobili"
   AND c.codec IN(2,0)
   AND d.id_immobile IS NULL  -- or omit this
 ORDER 
    BY c.id_campo
```